# UIButton moves out of highlighted mode after a second

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton, with this code to set the image based on the highlighted status:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = imageForButton(CGSizeMake(SquarePanelSize.width, SquarePanelSize.height), NO);
UIImage *buttonHighlightedImage = imageForButton(CGSizeMake(SquarePanelSize.width, SquarePanelSize.height), YES);
[self.addButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.addButton setImage:buttonHighlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

The problem is that I want it to stay highlighted when the user has their finger on it, but it goes back to normal after a second.

Comment: Maybe it will be better to use the `selected` state of the button. It was made for this exact case.

Answer (score 1):

had this issue myself a few days ago this was the fix i found throw this in your button was touched method/ ibaction

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(highlightButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.0];
```

and then have a highlight button method for that

```
-(void)highlightButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
   sender.highlighted = YES;
}
```

Comment: the image or highlight action you set will now stay after touch is released

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use setBackgroundImage method.

```
 [self.addButton setBackgroundImage:buttonHighlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

try this. It works fine for me. if this one didn't work then try this.

```
[self.addButton setImage:buttonHighlightedImage forState:(UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted)];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: Did you try setBackgourndImage for normal state. And what's your imageForButton method